# creating named scopes: do i need to declare that model before the attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When creating named scopes in a model, is it necessary to call the model before the attribute that you are using in your query?

Example

```
  scope :sorted, order('position ASC')
```

vs

```
  scope :sorted, order('pages.position ASC')
```

is the latter preferred, or inline with conventions? are there benefits to either? or is it just a matter of clarity or legibility?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **will** need to declare the model if the scope will be used with a join with another model, which has a field with the same name.

Say the `company has_one :contact`, and the `Contact` has a `position`. Then

```
Company.sorted.joins(:contact)
```

will complain (on the SQL level) that it's unclear which of the `position` fields should be used for sorting.

Otherwise it's optional.